# Группировка сообщений в БД с выводом последнего сообщения в группе

Tags: база-данных, sql, запрос, mysql

Добрый день!

Есть таблица сообщений message:

```
m_id | m_from | m_to | m_message
  1     1       2       text1
  2     2       1       text2
  3     1       3       text3
  4     3       1       text4
  5     1       4       text5
  6     5       2       text6
```

Необходимо сгруппировать отправителя и получателя таким образом, чтобы они входили в одну группу, при этом(!),
чтобы m_id был взят максимальным из этой группы, т.е.:

```
m_id | m_from | m_to | m_message
  2     2       1       text2
  6     5       2       text6
```

Пришел к следующему:

```
SELECT `m_id`, `m_from`, `m_to`, `m_message`, `m_from` + `m_to` AS `grouping` 
FROM `message` 
WHERE  
`m_from` =2 OR `m_to` =2
GROUP BY `grouping`

m_id | m_from | m_to | m_message | grouping
  1     1       2       text2       3
  6     5       2       text6       7
```

Но, данный запрос выдает первый попавшийся m_id (в данном случае m_id=1).

Каким образом можно составить запрос?

Спасибо!

Comment: Задача несложная, но условие непонятно. Почему остаётся именно две записи (т.е. по каким условиям формируются группы)?

Comment: >`m_from` + `m_to` AS `grouping` 

Т.е. 1 и 4, 2 и 3 - это что, одна группа?

Comment: alexiz:  Задача состоит в следующем: Мы знаем id пользователя. Должны выводиться пользователи: либо от которых пришло мне сообщение, либо которым было отправлено сообщение, т.е сгруппировать по пользователям, плюс к этому вывод последнего сообщения из переписки, которое которое он отправил, либо ему отправили (в данном случае max m_id из группы)
msi: мы знаем id получателя(он же может быть и отправителем), т.е. зная число 2, как в примере, мы не получим другую сумму 2+х, х+2

Comment: msi: мы знаем id получателя(он же может быть и отправителем), т.е. зная число 2, как в примере, мы не получим другую сумму 2+х, х+2

Comment: @idd

      select * from idd where m_id in 
        (select max(m_id) from idd where m_from = 2 
        union
        select max(m_id) from idd where m_to =2);

Comment: Если мы добавим строчку m_id=7|m_from=3|m_to=2|text7 - мы потеряем вариант с m_id=6|m_from=5|m_to=2|text6. Т.е. данный запрос возьмет max m_id из m_from и max m_id из m_to всей! таблицы. А нужно, чтобы для каждой группы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если я правильно понял,

```
    select * from message where m_id in
      (
      select MAX(m_id) from message
      where 2 in(m_from, m_to)
      group by case when m_from>m_to then m_to else m_from end, 
               case when m_from>m_to then m_from else m_to end
      )
```

Comment: Данный вариант не совсем подходит, ввиду того что если мы добавим строчку m_id=7|m_from=3|m_to=2|text7 - мы потеряем вариант с m_id=6|m_from=5|m_to=2|text6

Comment: Просто забыл еще один case добавить - надо же по паре группировать.
Исправил ответ.

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Если предположить, что вы организируете вывод переписки, то тогда у нас должен быть известным собственный ID (Возьмем например id = 2), тогда запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT MAX(m_id), IF(m_from = 2, m_to, m_from) AS `user`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `user`
```

Если же просто нужны все "диaлоги", то:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(`table`.`m_id`) AS `message_id`,
    COUNT(`table`.`m_id`) AS `all_messages`,
    IF (`table`.`m_from` > `table`.`m_to`, `table`.`m_to`, `table`.`m_from`) AS `lower`,
    IF (`table`.`m_from` > `table`.`m_to`, `table`.`m_from`, `table`.`m_to`) AS `upper`

FROM 
    `table`
GROUP BY `lower`,`upper`
```

---

Для быстрого теста оформил код на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bf35/2)

Comment: В случае 1 варианта с условием IF оно пробегается по всем вариантам, и если m_from не= 2 переходит к m_to, которое оно не проверяет равняется ли m_to двум. А нужно группировать только для одного пользователя c id =2

Comment: * WHERE m_to = 2 OR m_from = 2

Comment: Замечательно! Спасибо!